# CNF and DNF form of single logical variable

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form, disjunctive-normal-form

I am learning boolean algebra. So apologies for this naive question. During our discussion among friends, we came across following puzzle,

How can I convert following statement into CNF and DNF?

$$ A \wedge \neg A $$

Is it following for CNF?
$$ (A \vee A ) \wedge ( \neg A \vee \neg A) $$

Similarly, for DNF, is following correct?

$$ (A \wedge \neg A ) \vee ( A \wedge \neg A ) $$

I tried to use truth table method like shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636119/find-dnf-and-cnf-of-an-expression) post, but answer to this statement is always `false`. So how can I build DNF for such statement from truth table?

Comment: Cite a reference for CNF and DNF.  You will see that neither of your answers qualify.

Comment: Well, maybe they do qualify, but in fact there is never need for repetition, so $A \wedge \neg A$ is already in CNF and in DNF

Comment: @GEdgar, is it both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $(1)$

$$A\land\lnot A,\tag{1}$$

is already in CNF ([conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Examples_and_non-examples)), and DNF ([disjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form)).

All conjunctions of [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)) and all disjunctions of literals are in CNF, as they can be seen as conjunctions of one-literal [clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)) and conjunctions of a single clause, respectively. Vice versa for DNF formulas.

---

$$(A\lor A )\land(\lnot A \lor\lnot A)\tag{2}$$

$$(A \land \lnot A ) \lor ( A \ \land \lnot A )\tag{3}$$

$(2)$ and $(3)$ are in CNF and DNF respectively, however as @GEdgar has pointed out, there is no need for repetition of literals.